# How to add button to hide cell inputs in python jupyter notebook without nbextensions

Tags: python, button, jupyter, metadata, show-hide

I'm new to python and dont understand tag and cell metadata. I want to add button to hide cell input code in jupyter notebook itself, as shown in:  https://jupyterbook.org/interactive/hiding.html > Hide cell inputs. Can someone direct me please.

Comment: Got this: Adding tags using notebook interfaces >https://jupyterbook.org/content/metadata.html#jupyter-cell-tags. But how to add that button

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a button on the notebook you must have an extension fir that.

You can use an existing one like https://github.com/osscar-org/jupyterlab-hide-code or do it yourself.

Otherwise you can use the 'Collapse' commands in the 'view' menu.

Answer (score 0):

This javascript code creates a new button `Show/Hide code`, which shows/hides all code.

Button is visible in Python notebook as well as in HTML export and works in both of them.

```
from IPython.display import HTML

HTML('''<script>
code_show=true; 
function code_toggle() {
if (code_show){
$('div.input').hide();
} else {
$('div.input').show();
}
code_show = !code_show
} 
$( document ).ready(code_toggle);
</script>
<form action="javascript:code_toggle()"><input type="submit" value="Show/Hide code."></form>''')
```

Comment: Please put what versions of Jupyter Notebook this works for? At the time of this original post, Jupyter Notebook didn't run on the same components as JupyterLab. Now [with Jupyter Notebook 7+ having been out nearly a year now](https://blog.jupyter.org/announcing-jupyter-notebook-7-8d6d66126dcf) it is important to note such things if you are going to revive an old post. Does it only work in Jupyter Notebook < 6.5 and current NbClassic?